# "Generics add stability to your code by making more of your bugs detectable at compile time." - Explained in laymen's terms?

Tags: debugging, generics, types, compiler-errors

*"Generics add stability to your code by making more of your bugs detectable at compile time."*

I keep reading this everywhere, but I can't seem to find an explanation for why generics help make errors more detectable in compile time rather then run time.

**Maybe this might be answered somewhere else, but I'd really appreciate it if someone would take the time to explain this in layman's terms.** I'll be able to understand those other explanations if you do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine this scenario:

```
public class Bob(){}
public Class Tom(){}

List list = new List();
list.Add(new Bob());
list.Add(new Tom());
Tom tom = (Tom)list[0]; //oops wrong index
```

This will fail, but only at run time as a `Bob` isn't a `Tom`

```
List<Bob> list = new List<Bob>();
list.Add(new Bob());

Tom tom = list[0];
```

This will fail at compile time as the compiler can tell that the list can only contain `Bob`s and so the last statement is invalid, as you can't possible get a `Tom` out of the list as it is a list which can only contain `Bob`s.

similarly this code will fail at compile time as well:

```
list.Add(new Tom());
```

as the list is declared as being a list of `Bob`s and you are trying to add a `Tom`

Generics allow the compiler to know what types the code is dealing with and so can prevent you from trying to use a type which is invalid for the context.

So with generics you are basically saying to the compiler (in the example above):

> I have a list. Its a list of `Bob`s. Please only allow me to put `Bob`
>   instances into the list and make it an error if I try and put any
>   other type into the list.

Once you have done this you can't accidentally add anything else to the list. Which can be quite easy to do if you pass the list to a function and use it away from where you declared it.

in general generics is like a way to tell the compiler some extra information about the types that you are dealing with so it can help you not use types incorrectly

Comment: So basically, the benefit comes directly from using fewer casts, and generics make that possible?

Comment: Yes you have fewer casts, but the main benefit is that it is easier to write code which is verifiably correct, without issues related to using the wrong types